# Compiling in C with system

Tags: c

I need to compile a program with system, i have the name of the archive, and the name of the execute file, the son execute gcc -o file.c exe1 and the father execute ./exe1 for example

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>    

int main(int argc,char *argv[])
{
    if (argc != 3) {
        printf("Debe ingresar el nombre del archivo a compilar y el ejecutable");
        exit(1);
    } else  {
        char *archivo1 = strcat("gcc ", argv[1]);
        char *archivo2 = strcat(archivo1, ".c -o ");
        char *archivo3 = strcat(archivo2, argv[2]);
        char *ejecutable = strcat("./", argv[2]);    
        pid_t pid_hijo;
            int valor;
        switch(pid_hijo = fork()) {
            case -1:
                printf("No se pudo crear el hijo");
            case 0:
                valor = system(archivo3);
            default:
                wait(NULL);
                valor = system(ejecutable);
        }
    }        
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your `case` blocks should have `breaks`.

Comment: Give a look at sprintf() instead of strcat

Answer (score 2):

This

```
char *archivo1=strcat("gcc ",argv[1]);
```

is undefined behavior.

In [c](/questions/tagged/c) `"gcc "` is a string literal and it's read only, `strcat()` will try to write to it and actually beyond the end of `"gcc "`, trying to write beyond the end of an array is also undefined behavior, but in this case it's not an array so it's illegal from any point of view.

You need `snprintf()` instead, like this

```
char command[200];
ssize_t result;
result = snprintf(command, sizeof(command), "gcc %s -o %s", argv[1], argv[2]) ;
if (result >= (ssize_t) sizeof(command))
    error_cannot_store_the_command_in_command():
```

Comment: @cad Yes you can `[tag:c]`.

Comment: not found for me :/ this return a segmentation fault

Comment: What did you change exactly?

Comment: My code cannot case a segmentation fault as it is unless `argv[1]` or `argv[2]` are uninitialized.

Comment: @JMateoPinedaLop. No, ask another question with the new issue. Please accept one of the answers here because the segmentation fault seems to be from something different. And when I said *my code* I meant the one posted here.